# Getting the json data from the website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry I am a bit new to this so I would like to get a certain json data `"getMe":"IneedThisData"`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">utag_cfg_ovrd = window.utag_cfg_ovrd || {};utag_cfg_ovrd.noview = true;
</script>
<script async="" src="/assets/AppMeasurement.js">
</script>
<script>
    window.REDUX_STATE = {"appConfig":
    {"dataLab":"energy","minimum":"maximum","getMe":"IneedThisData"}}
</script>

</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', 'window.REDUX_STATE').text)
```

I getting an error of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` 
Im still stuck in loading that data into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `"minimum":"maximum":"getMe"` is a typo, and actually is `"minimum":"maximum","getMe"` without typo (that makes it a proper JSON), you can use following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("script", text=re.compile(".*window\.REDUX_STATE.*"))
text = str(tag.contents[0])
splits = text.split("=")
data = json.loads(splits[1])
```

In your code, `soup.find('script', 'window.REDUX_STATE')` does not match any tag. That is the reason you are getting `AttributeError` error.
`attrs` attribute of [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)) is used to filter tags based on their attribute. "window.REDUX_STATE" is not an attribute.

Comment: I really like the approach. Thanks